# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges as sysdba for sys (even after giving orapwd command)

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I have installed an oracle 11g instance on a linux machine. After doing a DB bounce by issuing shutdown immediate and startup. Not able to login as `sys/password@sid` as sysdba. Even issued a

```
orapwd file=orapwsid  password=password entries=30 force=y
```

command, which created a pwd file also.

But still not able to login as sys. I can connect to the DB by scott and other users created but not as a sysdba.
Request you to help me.

Comment: What is the error message? Could you connect as sys locally (sqlplus / as sysdba)?

Comment: for sqlplus / as sysdba it gives me "ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified" and sqlplus /@sid it gives me insufficient privileges

Comment: You had to set the SID before connect locally. set ORACLE_SID=SID ans after sqlplus / as sysdba

Comment: I have set the ORACLE_SID, PATH and ORACLE_HOME

Comment: See [**How to resolve sqlplus / as sysdba : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges**](http://lalitkumarb.com/category/oracle-database-administration/)

Answer (score 6):

I got into same issue but did not know that I have to switch to oracle user to get dba access.

```
$ cd ORACLE_HOME/xe/bin 
$ ls -la oracle
-rwsr-s--x 1 oracle dba 165700472 Aug 28  2011 oracle
$ su oracle
$ sqlplus sys as sysdba
```

You should be able to login without any issues

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are a *dba!*

```
[bb@limbo] ~/ $ . oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [XE] ? XE
ORACLE_BASE environment variable is not being set since this
information is not available for the current user ID bb.
You can set ORACLE_BASE manually if it is required.

[bb@limbo] ~/ $ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 16 19:02:11 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

sys@XE> exit

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

[bb@limbo] ~/ $ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 16 19:05:56 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Enter user-name: 
[bb@limbo] ~/ $ su -c "usermod -G dba bb"

Password: 

[bb@limbo] ~/ $ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Jan 16 19:06:29 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

sys@XE>
```

Comment: Hello , I know this was posted a long time ago , but is there a way to revoke the whole process , "un-granting" dba traits to an user?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolved this issue by making sure the instance name case sensitive in listener file. Also the orapw file. If the SID are small case, I make sure all related files using the smaller case intance name.

Answer (score 0):

```
> $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus as sysdba
```

this would work if your $ORACLE_HOME is set correctly

to check your $ORACLE_HOME run

```
> echo $ORACLE_HOME
```

this will display oracle home path